# Comparing dates in view and applying class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am currently displaying projects within a view using a foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('projects.destroy', $project->id))) !!}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading projectPanelHeading">
                    <h4>{{ $project->projectName  }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body projectPanel">
                    <p>Deployment Date: {{ ($project->deploymentDate ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($project->deploymentDate)) : '') }}</p>
                    <p>Status: {{ $project->status or '' }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

As you can see, each project has a $project->deploymentDate which I convert to a date object with the format d-m-Y.

What I am trying to do is compare the deploymentDate with the current date, and if the deploymentDate has passed, to apply a panel-red class to the panel.

I was thinking about doing something like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('projects.destroy', $project->id))) !!}
    @if(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($project>deploymentDate)) < date('d-m-Y'))
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-red">
            <div class="panel-heading projectPanelHeading">
                <h4>{{ $project->projectName  }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body projectPanel">
                <p>Deployment Date: {{ ($project->deploymentDate ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($project->deploymentDate)) : '') }}</p>
                <p>Status: {{ $project->status or '' }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @else
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading projectPanelHeading">
                <h4>{{ $project->projectName  }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body projectPanel">
                <p>Deployment Date: {{ ($project->deploymentDate ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($project->deploymentDate)) : '') }}</p>
                <p>Status: {{ $project->status or '' }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What I do not like about this approach is the repetition of the panel block.  Additionally, there are a lot of mistakes with panel-red being applied to projects who's deploymentDate has not yet passed, and vice versa.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am after which is both correct, and does not require repetition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add the `deploymentDate` attribute to the `$dates` array in your Project model. This will ensure you have Carbon instances for your `deploymentDate`.

#### Project.php

```
protected $dates = ['deploymentDate'];
```

Once achieved you can check the if it's less than by simple function:

```
@if($project->deploymentDate->lt(\Carbon\Carbon::Now()))
```

This can also be achieved by a method on the model, in your Project.php

```
public function checkDeploymentDate()
{
    return $this->deploymentDate->lt(\Carbon\Carbon::Now());
}
```

Then in your views:

```
@if($project->checkDeploymentDate())
```

Finally for the panel part, you can add a Blade directive for it:

#### AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('deploymentDate', function($expression) {
            return "<?php echo($expression); ?>";
        });
    }

}
```

Blade directives will help you extend new functionality to your Blade templates. So in the above example, in your view template:

`{{@deploymentDate(test)}}` will echo test

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the date part works perfectly.  Could you elaborate on the ServiceProvider?  How would this be implemented?  Thanks